# Is it possible to directly modify the html code that VsCode runs on?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I want to embed a video directly into the vscode editor using iframe. After playing around with dev tools, I realized that the entire editor is based on HTML, and I was wondering if it was possible for me to somehow access that HTML and edit it to add an  line in it?

Comment: Sure. Fork it on github and add it.

Comment: there is an extension to inject HTML/CSS code in the application files